# How to import a dataset directly into my javascript code

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I would like to know if I could import a dataset directly into my code (javascript), because I want to make a condition for when the user presses a certain function, to display a given dataset.

Comment: What's the format of this dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get your data in String format as JSON array or dictionary you can just use `JSON.parse()` to create an object from your data in string format. Then use that object for extracting all info for display. [Here are some examples](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

From w3schools:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
obj.name // "John"
obj.age  // 30
obj.city // "New York"
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a fetch request to get data that you can display.

```
fetch('http://localhost:portOfDatabase/path')
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(r => {
  //use r which holds the response from your database
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the tags you have added it seems as if you would like to add a dataset you can use to populate a Mapbox map.

As the other answers mentioned, you can load data from a JSON file. Please note that the data needs to be of [geoJSON format](https://geojson.org/).

This would create the geoJSON data source at runtime. But you can also point it to a source file. (see second code snippet)

```js
map.addSource('route', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'properties': {},
'geometry': {
'type': 'LineString',
'coordinates': [
[-122.48369693756104, 37.83381888486939],
[-122.48348236083984, 37.83317489144141],
[-122.48339653015138, 37.83270036637107],
[-122.48356819152832, 37.832056363179625]
]
}
}
)
```

From file:

```js
  map.addSource(<sourcename>, {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': <URL> 
        });
```

Please also see these examples:

- [Adding a geoJSON line](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-line/)
- [Adding multiple geometries from geoJSON](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/multiple-geometries/)